# Can studying older material help an advanced learner to understand and use contemporary English better?

Tags: teaching

One of my favorite methods of expanding my knowledge of a language is to pick up a book and analyse the hell out of it, by glossing and making notes and trying my best to understand and absorb everything, and listening to each chapter from the audiobook (if available) several times before going on to the next, repeating after the narrator and trying to exactly copy the pronunciation and accent.

As a self-educating learner of English, I have carried out the above on a couple contemporary works of English literature, and have benefited a great deal from it. But unfortunately, my time is very limited and I have to be careful about which books to choose to work on.

My question here is if I should stick with contemporary works. What happens if I do this with, say, a play by Shakespeare? (It shouldn't be a very difficult task with all these annotated editions and online help at hand.) Would it improve my understanding of the foundations of the language? I really enjoy reading classic literature, but I'm afraid that it'll do more harm than good.

My first aim is to master contemporary English as best I can, and I find that paying attention to historical and etymological aspects can sometimes speed up and deepen my learning. But I don't want to pick up too much archaic words and obsolete constructions involuntarily and make myself sound plain bizarre.

Please know that I'm not at all asking for suggestions about particular works I could study. I'm looking for more general answers, especially from experienced teachers and other knowledgeable users.

Answer (score 1):

What an excellent question! I realize you are not at all looking for specific suggestions, but I thought this might be worth sharing with you nevertheless.

I had a professor who stated, "No one can be considered literate in English without having read the major works of Shakespeare and at least the more important books of the King James Bible."

Shakespeare and the King James Bible are the sources of uncountable references in both modern and classic English and American literature. I am neither a Christian nor someone who studies the Bible, but I recommend skimming this report if you have the time: http://www.bibleliteracy.org/bibcdocs/BibleLiteracyReport2006.pdf

You asked, "Would it improve my understanding of the foundations of the language?" The answer is "Yes, absolutely."

Your English is already excellent. I don't think that reading classics with variant spellings and odd punctuation will confuse you at all.

You might want to pick up a good used copy of *The Riverside Shakespeare*, which has useful (and thankfully brief) footnotes throughout. If you want to read a facsimile of the original first printing of the *1611 King James Bible*, I can recommend this site: http://greatsite.com/facsimile-reproductions/kingjames-1611.html

If you sign up for greatsite's infrequent newsletter, they will email you a link to their digitized bibles, fully indexed by "books" (chapters), which you can view for free.

Your use of audiobooks is brilliant, especially if your study of contemporary literature in English is mainly limited to your commute to and from work, as it is for so many people who don't otherwise have the time they would like to read.